# Swift code doesn't work on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, swift, sprite-kit, arc4random

I just finished my swift game and I would try it on all devices. 
I just note that, before the iPhone 5S, all device doesn't work with `arc4random`. The iPhone 5 is a 32bit device and `arc4random`return a UInt32 and it will cause an overflow if the random number is too big. I tried to replace `arc4random` by `arc4random_uniform` as onevcat said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719472/ios-8-code-working-on-iphone-5s-but-not-iphone-5). 
But still doesn't work.

See my code and a screen shot error bellow :

```
var lastYieldTimeInterval:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()
var lastUpdatetimeInterval:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()
var lastUpdatetimeIntervalBl:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()
var lastYieldTimeIntervalrou:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()
var lastYieldTimeIntervalro:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()
var lastYieldTimeIntervalj:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()
var lastYieldTimeIntervalvio:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()
var lastYieldTimeIntervalv:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()
var lastYieldTimeIntervalora:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()
var lastYieldTimeIntervaln:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()
var lastYieldTimeIntervalGold:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval()


func updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(timeSinceLastUpdate:CFTimeInterval){


    let minInterval = UInt32(0)
    let maxInterval = UInt32(1500)
    let rangeInterval = UInt32(maxInterval - minInterval)




    lastYieldTimeInterval += timeSinceLastUpdate
    let intervalbl = Int(arc4random_uniform(rangeInterval)) + Int(minInterval)
    if (lastYieldTimeInterval > NSTimeInterval(intervalbl)){
        lastYieldTimeInterval = 0
        addBalloonbl()

    }

    lastYieldTimeIntervalj += timeSinceLastUpdate

    let intervalj = Int(arc4random_uniform(rangeInterval)) + Int(minInterval)
    if (lastYieldTimeIntervalj > NSTimeInterval(intervalj)){
        lastYieldTimeIntervalj = 0
        addBalloonj()
        }

    lastYieldTimeIntervalora += timeSinceLastUpdate
    let intervalora = Int(arc4random_uniform(rangeInterval)) + Int(minInterval)
    if (lastYieldTimeIntervalora > NSTimeInterval(intervalora)){
        lastYieldTimeIntervalora = 0
        addBalloonora()
    }


    lastYieldTimeIntervalrou += timeSinceLastUpdate
    let intervalrou = Int(arc4random_uniform(rangeInterval)) + Int(minInterval)
    if (lastYieldTimeIntervalrou > NSTimeInterval(intervalrou)){
        lastYieldTimeIntervalrou = 0
        addBalloonrou()
    }


    lastYieldTimeIntervalro += timeSinceLastUpdate
    let intervalro = Int(arc4random_uniform(rangeInterval)) + Int(minInterval)
    if (lastYieldTimeIntervalro > NSTimeInterval(intervalro)){
        lastYieldTimeIntervalro = 0
        addBalloonro()
    }


    lastYieldTimeIntervalvio += timeSinceLastUpdate
    let intervalvio = Int(arc4random_uniform(rangeInterval)) + Int(minInterval)
    if (lastYieldTimeIntervalvio > NSTimeInterval(intervalvio)){
        lastYieldTimeIntervalvio = 0
        addBalloonvio()
    }


    lastYieldTimeIntervalv += timeSinceLastUpdate
    let intervalv = Int(arc4random_uniform(rangeInterval)) + Int(minInterval)
    if (lastYieldTimeIntervalv > NSTimeInterval(intervalv)){
        lastYieldTimeIntervalv = 0
        addBalloonv()
    }


    let minIntervalBl = 1
    let maxIntervalBl = 3000
    let rangeIntervalBl = maxIntervalBl - minIntervalBl


    lastYieldTimeIntervaln += timeSinceLastUpdate
    let intervaln = Int(arc4random()) % Int(rangeIntervalBl) + Int(minIntervalBl)
    if (lastYieldTimeIntervaln > NSTimeInterval(intervaln)){
        lastYieldTimeIntervaln = 0
        addBalloonnoir()
    }

    let minIntervalGold = 4
    let maxIntervalGold = 3000
    let rangeIntervalGold = maxIntervalGold - minIntervalGold


    lastYieldTimeIntervalGold += timeSinceLastUpdate
    let intervalGold = Int(arc4random()) % Int(rangeIntervalGold) + Int(minIntervalGold)
    if (lastYieldTimeIntervalGold > NSTimeInterval(intervalGold)){
        lastYieldTimeIntervalGold = 0
        addBalloongold()
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I assume that the real error message is that 'Int' is not convertible to **'UInt32'** ?

Comment: Yes you're right. I use the question you mentioned. Despite my correction I still have the same error (see the screenshot). It stop on `lastYieldTimeInterval += timeSinceLastUpdate` I updated the question with the new code

Comment: That's the same problem: lastYieldTimeInterval and timeSinceLastUpdate have different types. Swift does not implicitly convert types.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what I have to do :( my knowledge is very limited. I'm just coding since few weeks :(

Comment: My last comment was actually wrong (lastYieldTimeInterval and timeSinceLastUpdate are both Double). I don't see why the code should crash on that line. I have reopened the question ...

Comment: That's why I didn't found anything about other type of timeSinceLastUpdate in the apple documentation. Thank you for your help and for reopening the question

Comment: please copy/paste errors as text, do not make screenshots of xcode

Answer (score 0):

I found why this doesn't work. Actually it is not `timesincelastupdate` but still the `arc4random`. I forgot to replace it on two lines. Now Everything is working...

Thank you for your help